# how to to put a shell script in crontab in solaris to automate the script

Tags: cron

```
#!/bin/bash
# Checks rather system is running Linux or Solaris
function osCheck {
        os_type=$(uname -i)
        echo "Checking OS type."
        case ${os_type} in
                "x86_64")
                        linuxDiskCheck
                        ;;
                *)
                        solarisDiskCheck
                        ;;
        done
```

this is just test script

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Have you gone through the documentation for [cron on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/sysrescron-24589.html)? Is there a more specific issue you want to address?

Comment: You might want to check the syntax of your script at https://shellcheck.net/ It's missing several lines at the bottom, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let suppose your script is located in `/path/to/script.sh`. You should make it executable:

```
chmod 700 /path/to/script.sh
```

Then executing `crontab -e` you get open editor (probably `vi`) where you enter

```
0 2 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

This will execute the script once per day at 2h 0 minutes in the night.
If you want to execute it every 4 hours you can enter (Linux)

```
0 */4 * * *  /path/to/script.sh
```

For Solaris you may need to enter the record on this way:

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * *  /path/to/script.sh
```

You may redirect the STDOUT and/or STDERR to file by your choise